# divison by zero; is it a run time error or compile time error?

Tags: c

While running this code I am getting a floating point exception.

Why was the text `zero divison error` not printed? It should have been printed because `printf("zero divison error")` is executed *before* the division by zero happens.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p=0;int a=2;
    printf("zero divison error");
    printf("%d",a/p);
    // why zero divison error is not printed? 
    // i am getting floating point exception(core dumped).
}
```

Comment: Who is supposed to "print" the error? Of course it is runtime error as the denominator can get different values in the runtime.

Comment: The title doesn't match the question in the post. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: Dividing by zero is *undefined behavior* (for integer types or floating point numbers in non-IEEE environments) - the standard doesn't say it raises an exception

Comment: Strictly speaking, there are no runtime errors in C. Whatever can be compiled can run, but if it invokes *undefined behavior*, anything could happen

Comment: Please copy/paste the output of the program into your question. In other words: what exactly does your program print when the runtime error happends?

Comment: This is not a duplicate, OP's question is about why the sentence is not showing up. Read more carefully guys.

Answer (score 5):

The standard output is line-buffered by default *on your implementation*. `printf("zero division error");` wrote the characters into the buffer, but the buffer wasn't flushed yet. Add a new-line `\n` there or flush the output with `fflush(stdout);`. If the output is not flushed before your application crashes, the contents of the buffer are lost.

---

As for the error, [C11 6.5.5p5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p5):

> The result of the `/` operator is the quotient from the division of the first operand by the second; the result of the `%` operator is the remainder. In both operations, if the value of the second operand is zero, the **behavior is undefined.**

Some examples of what might happen are given in the standard ([C11 3.4.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.4.3)):

> 2 NOTE Possible undefined behavior ranges from **ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results**, to **behaving during translation or program execution in a documented manner** characteristic of the environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to **terminating** a translation or **execution (with the issuance of a diagnostic message)**.

So terminating execution with a diagnostic message (which you did) is just one possibility. The C compiler can also refuse to compile the program, or the program when run can set the result to 0, or 42; or ignore the calculation altogether.

When I run the program, I get

```
% ./a.out 
zsh: floating point exception (core dumped)  ./a.out
```

This corresponds to the program terminating with `SIGFPE`; while it stands for SIGnal, Floating-Point Exception, the standard says that [`SIGFPE`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.14p3) could be raised upon

> an erroneous arithmetic operation, such as **zero divide** or an operation
>                      resulting in overflow

At the moment when the signal handler is called, it is no longer known what the actual operation was, and so no other diagnostics is printed.

Comment: @Fabien now it is

Comment: @Fabien the main question is that which is in title: is the division by zero a runtime error or compile-time error.

Comment: Great answer, but I agree that OP is confused about missing prints, rather than *how exactly division by zero is handled*.

Comment: Yeah I just saw that the title is really confusing and not matching the content of the question. I will remove my DV.

Comment: "The standard output is line-buffered by default" --> I have not found where C specifies this.  Any citation for this common practice?

Comment: @chux implementation-specified but OP is clearly using such a system

Answer (score 3):

Everybody downvote like crazy, without even taking time to read your question, so I repost and hope that people will take time to read better, both question and answers.

Your question is why the sentence `zero divison error` does not show, because you `printf()` it before dividing by zero.

**The answer is:**

Data sent to stdout are buffered, and you did not provide any newline character at end of string so the line stayed buffered before the application crash.

Use `fflush(stdout);` to flush `stdout` before dividing by zero, or add a `\n` and it will show up correctly.

**Code reviewed:**

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int p=0;int a=2;
    // This will show: the \n will flush the string on stdout
    printf("zero divison error\n");
    // This might not show, the operation can fail before the call to printf()
    printf("%d",a/p);
}
```

Comment: The reason for downvotes is incorrect claims like *this will crash*. Of course, the part about buffering was correct.

Comment: "\n will flush the string on stdout" --> `'\n'` often flushes a buffer, yet `stdout` is not specified to be _line_ buffered.  Best to use `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: In his context, the application receives an unhandled signal, so it will crash :-/ He even states that it crashes. the answer cannot be too general. I removed that part to satisfy reviewers.